# Linq conditional statement and next item comparison

Tags: c#, .net, linq, list

I have a list of `new List<Tuple<int, int>>` and would like to test if `Item2` is 0 and has an object following that current item.

Basically the last item in the list would bring back false since it wouldnt have a following item.

```
times.Any(q => q.Item2 == 0 // && has an item following it)
```

Comment: Isn't it easier to execute the query against all but the last item?

Comment: What if two last items of the list have Item2 == 0 ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple enough, just ignore the last element before your `Any` call:

```
times.Take(times.Count - 1).Any(q => q.Item2 == 0)
```

You can do this because you have an `ICollection<T>`, so you can retrieve the `Count`.